# Paperclip and S3: Multiple thumbnail sizes not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip to handle image uploads for my Rails app, and it's working great when I use system storage: multiple thumbnail sizes ("styles" in Paperclip parlance) are saved to file, and I can access any of them by passing the style name to the url method.

When I set up the app to store images on S3 (using the aws-s3 gem), however, only one image is stored in my S3 bucket.  For what it's worth, only the *last* style listed is stored.  So, if in my model, I've got:

```
  has_attached_file :photo,
                :styles         => { :large  => "1000x1000>", 
                                     :medium => "600x600>", 
                                     :thumb  => "200x200>" },
                :storage        => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                :bucket         => AppConstants.bucket,
                :path           => "pictures/:id/:filename"
```

Only the "thumb" size will be saved to S3.

Has anybody encountered a similar problem?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure why this works locally, but you didn't specify `:style` in your path declaration.

Comment: That's it exactly.  Thanks for the quick reply, Benoit.

Comment: A good reminder and easy to miss if you implement thumbnails or alternate sizes later in development (like I did). Note that if you don't have :style specified in your path declaration, you could get undesired results silently. (If they're the same format the thumbnail version will overwrite the original file; probably not what you wanted.)