# Paperclip cropping original image because of thumbnail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

So what I'm trying to do is have a centrally cropped image for the thumbnail and then also have the original image untouched so I can click on the thumbnail and bring the user to the original image.

So inside my model I have:

```
has_attached_file :image,
  default_url: "/assets/missing.png",
  url: "s3_domain_url",
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: "#{Rails.root}/config/aws-#{Rails.env}.yml",
  s3_permissions: 'authenticated-read',
  path: "/users/:id/images/:basename.:extension",
  s3_server_side_encryption: :aes256,
  styles: { thumb: "200x200#" }

def s3_url(style = nil, expires_in = 30.seconds)
  if image.exists?
    image.s3_object(style).url_for(:read, :secure => true, :expires => expires_in).to_s
  else
    "/assets/missing.png"
  end
end

validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

And then inside my HTML I've got: `<%= link_to image_tag(@challenge.s3_url(:thumb)), @challenge.s3_url(:original) %>`

This should allow for the user to click the thumbnail and then it should take them to the original image. But currently it has the correct cropped thumbnail and then when the user clicks it, it will take them to just a larger version of the cropped thumbnail, not the original image.

Is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: What if you try `@challenge.s3_url`?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel, I did that too and it's basically the same as doing @challenge.s3_url(:original). It's still cropped like a large thumb, whereas I want the actual original image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the same as [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300866/paperclip-and-s3-multiple-thumbnail-sizes-not-saving) Basically, needed to add a `:style` into the path. Now it works correctly.

So it now looks like:

```
has_attached_file :image,
  default_url: "/assets/missing.png",
  url: "s3_domain_url",
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: "#{Rails.root}/config/aws-#{Rails.env}.yml",
  s3_permissions: 'authenticated-read',
  path: "/users/:id/images/:style/:basename.:extension",
  s3_server_side_encryption: :aes256,
  styles: { thumb: "200x200#" }
```